# Mosfet won't turn fully on

Tags: mosfet, switches, power-electronics, mosfet-driver, fet

I have a [IPB011N04LG N channel MOSFET](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/418824/INFINEON/IPB011N04LG.html) configured as a switch in the following circuit:

[image: IPB as a switch]

It works, but doesn't turn fully on.

- If \$V_{\text{BAT}}\$ is \$23\$V I get \$11\$V on the load side
- If \$V_{\text{BAT}}\$ is \$16\$V I get \$7\$V on the load side

Did I make a mistake? How do I drive this MOSFET properly to fully switch on the load?

Comment: @MattYoung, done (and comment removed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is it is not configured as a switch. It is configured as a source follower. To make it switch fully on, you need the gate to be some volts above the source. Since the gate is held at about 0.5*VBAT by the voltage divider R7 and R8, anything that tends to drive the source above this level will start to turn "off" the FET.

This will have roughly the same effect as a BJT emitter follower, although the gate-source drop is harder to predict than a BJT's base-emitter drop. The voltage at VBUS will be a little bit below 0.5*VBAT, which is exactly what you see.

If you want to use it as a switch, you have a few options:

- Move the NMOS FET to the low side of the load.
- Use a PMOS FET on the high side and invert the gate-drive logic.
- Add a charge pump circuit so the MOSFET gate can be driven above VBAT.

Comment: You said it better than I started to.

Comment: Lovely    I add a charge pump.   Because I'm using a pwm to drive the gate:  any dc dc converter with 25 volts out to the gate should be fine right ?